# Getting "entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64" on archive but not on build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

My app works perfectly fine when building and running it on both the simulator and my physical device running iOS 15. However, when I go to archive it in preparation for the App Store, I get the following error:

```
ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did rename the app and some of the folders, but I made sure that all paths in the project build settings were updated to reflect these changes.

The app is SwiftUI, and I use no `AppDelegate` (some other answers refer to missing `@UIApplicationMain`). There is also a Widget extension - but I see `@main` used in their respective App/Widget classes.

Environment details:

- Xcode 13 (RC)
- iOS 15 (RC) on both simulator and physical iPhone X device

Comment: Do you have any build settings with different values for debug/release mode that could be the issue?

Comment: Did you succeed in fixing this issue ? I am facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your Development Assets build setting is set to a folder that contains your App struct or your AppDelegate, you will get this issue.

Comment: Thank you! After hours of debugging this is what finally fixed the error for me. No idea how Development Assets got set to that but deleting the value there fixed it.